# What does full LINQ support mean?

Tags: linq

Some O/RM tooling claim they have "Full LINQ support". What does that mean? Do they support all the LINQ operators ?

Answer (score 2):

I would think by "Full Linq Support" they mean that you can write linq queries against their objects, using their own IQueryable and IQueryProvider implementation, and have it support all standard LINQ extension methods.

At the absolute minimum, I would expect it to support all of the LINQ query syntax (from.. where.. select.. group etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagin that means they support LINQ to SQL, not just running LINQ queries on collection objects